# Check for firefox profile and create if it doesn't exist using Java

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, automation

So I have a requirement wherein a script installs an application automatically post which it will trigger a Gradle script which will then build and execute Selenium tests on the application.

The problem is, there is no guarantee that the systems on which this will run will have default or any other Firefox profiles available. Although we can create the profile using:

```
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile(new File("D:\\Selenium"));
```

But the tests I have run totally independent of each other so they create a new WebDriver object everytime. Creating a new profile for every test doesn't seem to be very efficient.

Anyways, what I'd like to do is to check if a firefox profile ("default") exists (can be on windows/linux) and if not create it once and for all.
Please advise if this is possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

If any specific profile is not required as per requirement, then we can start firefox straight away..

```
 WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
```

If need any specific profile, good to choose by name instead of this directory. collecting profile from directory is not recommended as per doc.

```
    ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("selenium");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

please go this [link](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/) to create profile and use this for all tests. Even if specified named "selenium" profile is not there, still execution starts by creating new profile by webdriver it self.

to create profile automatically,

```
//changing firefox default options
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2); //dont take default download folder
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);//dont show download box
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","c:\\downloads");//provide download location
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv"); //dont ask save as for provided types
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks but I'd like to do the profile creation part automatically. Is that possible? And I will need some profile. I have to set custom profile options for automatic file download and all.

Comment: @manpreetbhamba updated the answer to create profile by scripting

Comment: Can I possibly save this profile at once and use it for further tests?

Comment: then create profile manually.. so that you can use it by calling its name. if profile is create by script, it will lost once execution is over.